# Calling shell script using check_call

Tags: python

I am running into following error while calling shell script,how do I call shellscript using check_call or through anyother python function?
    import os
    from subprocess import check_call,Popen, PIPE

```
def main ():
    BUILD_ROOT="//local/mnt/workspace//AU"
    os.chdir(BUILD_ROOT)
    print os.getcwd()
    check_call(['./test.sh'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ERROR:-

```
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 8, in main
    check_call(['./test.sh'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 493, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding shell=True fixed it

```
check_call(['./test.sh'],shell=True)
```